# how to auto increase data field in java oop class

Tags: java, class, auto-increment

I have this class

```
public class NInfo {
private  int val;
private static int indx=1;

public NInfo(int val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.indx++;
    }
}
```

I would like to auto increase the indx in every new object that I create starting 1
this code doesnt work , what shall I fix ?

Comment: This should work though, but you have to use `NInfo.indx++` instead of `this.indx++` (or even simply `indx++`). Side note: it's a matter of taste, but I would name the field `index` rather than `indx` (no need to remove the `e`).

Comment: Make another variable `index` and set to it `this.indx++`. Static variable belongs to the class and not to the object.

Comment: What do you think is hapenning here ?

Answer (score 4):

A static field is shared by every instance of the class.  You need to store the value in a new field specific to the instance.

```
public class NInfo {
private  int val;
private int index;
private static int indx=1;

public NInfo(int val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.index = indx++;
    }
}
```

I would be interested in why you would like to add these indexes to each class.

Comment: You probably want to pre-increment this. Also indx is static and shouldn't be referred to with this.

Comment: @cogsmos Just noticed the static piece.  Why preincrement?  The first instance would have a value of 2?

Comment: Also this isn't thread safe, but that might not be an issue for this application.

Answer (score 1):

Every object of a class has all the attributes and methods defined in a class except the static ones. The static variables and methods are not part of the instance of the class. `this.` operator is used to refer to the particular instance of the class. To refer to a static variable you need not instantiate the object. You can directly refer to the variable using `ClassName.variableName` . So every time you create  a new instance of the variable in the code, indx is incremented (starting from 2 since you have post-incremented it).

In order to assign a new incremented value to an object, increment indx and assign it to a variable that is actually a part of the class instance(i.e. a variable that is not static).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the assignment <s>operator</s> operation.

```
NInfo.indx += 1;
```

***EDIT***:

```
public class NInfo {

  private int id;
  private int value;

  private static int index; // auto initialized to 0

  public NInfo(int value) {
    this.val = val;
    this.id = NInfo.index += 1;
  }

}
```

Comment: `+= 1` is exactly the same as `++`.

Comment: @sp00m Yes, I know that. I like my code to be less verbose. (NInfo.indx = ++NInfo.indx;) Just saving some keystrokes mate. You misunderstood me.

Comment: @sp00m It was a matter of taste mate. :)

Comment: No, I mean `i = i + 1`, `i += 1` and `i++` are all equal. `i = ++i` will increase the value twice.

Comment: No @sp00m, why would i = ++i increment twice? It will increment first and then assign but would increment just once.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass like an attribute the indx in the constructor, and increase the index where you create a

Comment: You should rephrase this answer; it's not at all clear to me what you're trying to say.